# Can't change radio button background color on Tailwind V3

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I need ur guys help how to change BG color of radio button here's my code.
`<input type="radio" className="form-radio h-6 w-6 checked:bg-white text-green-500  p-3 my-4" name="radio" value="1"  />`
the output still the same as default radio button. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwsjM.png)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use **:checked** property to achieve this.

```
input[type="radio"]:checked {
    background-color: #your-color
}
```

Check out a custom radio button design in [codepen](https://codepen.io/amasci/pen/vMGVaz).

Answer (score 7):

You have to use `@tailwindcss/forms` - a plugin that provides a basic reset for form styles that makes form elements easy to override with utilities.

- Install the plugin from npm:

```
# Using npm
npm install @tailwindcss/forms

# Using Yarn
yarn add @tailwindcss/forms
```

- Add the plugin to your `tailwind.config.js` file:

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    // ...
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    // ...
  ],
}
```

- Then you can use Tailwind utility classes:

```html
 <input type="radio" class="h-6 w-6 checked:bg-green-500 text-green-500 p-3 my-4" name="radio" value="1" />
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/6oxQ5F0cXT

---

The solution described is fully compatible with Tailwind v3.0 - according to official [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#official-plugins):

> All of our first-party plugins have been updated for compatibility with v3.0

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy ! i was facing this issue, and that fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue: I was able to change the background color of my input radio, but on iOS Safari it remained blue when it was selected.

The correct mix of TailwindCSS classes to make it with the wished color everywhere:

```
<label class="ml-3 mb-1 block">
  <input type="radio" class="checked:bg-emerald-400 checked:hover:bg-emerald-400 checked:active:bg-emerald-400 checked:focus:bg-emerald-400 focus:bg-emerald-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-emerald-400" name="radio" checked />
  <span>Hello</span>
</label>
```

See the demo there: https://play.tailwindcss.com/LNjVfTqF29

Comment: This did it for me. You covered all the bases lol! It's crazy that it takes so much to change the color of a radio button though. Tailwind should make this much easier.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `accent-[#1E7BAE]` class in your project, This will easily change the color of the radio buttons (This class is tested in tailwind v3.3 and next js)

```
<input type="radio" className="form-radio accent-[#1E7BAE]" name="option" value="male" />
```

Answer (score 0):

it's simple use Tailwind's text color utilities example "text-indigo-600",  You can customize the background color of a radio button when it's checked by using Tailwind's text color utilities, like text-indigo-600

example :

```html
<label class="inline-flex items-center">
        <input type="radio" class="form-radio text-indigo-600" name="radio-colors" value="1" checked>
        <span class="ml-2">Option 1</span>
 </label>
```

Reference : https://tailwindcss-custom-forms.netlify.app/